# How to recursively get path between related objects?

Tags: php

**How do I create a recursive class function that will trace the path between related objects?**

Data:

```
ID  Name          ParentID

1   Egypt         0

2   USA           0

3   Giza          1

4   6th october   3
```

Function call such as `addressPath(4)` should produce this output:

> Egypt->Giza->6th october

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some of the confusion may have come from the distinction between an object and a collection of objects. For this possible solution, I used a class for each so that the function could belong to the collection class.

The recursive function itself is commented line-by-line, so I hope it's clear enough.

```
<?php

class related_object {

  public $ID;
  public $Name;
  public $ParentID;

  public function __construct($id, $name, $parent=0) {
    $this->ID = $id;
    $this->Name = $name;
    $this->ParentID = $parent;
  }

}

class related_object_library {

  public $objects;

  public function add($object) {
    $this->objects []= $object;
  }

  public function addressPath($id, $path='') {

    // iterate through each object in collection
    foreach ($this->objects as $object){

      // if ID matches, then return Name
      if ($object->ID === $id) {
        $path = $object->Name.$path;

        // if it has a parent, then recurse, else just return
        if (!empty($object->ParentID))
          return $this->addressPath($object->ParentID,"->$path");
        else return $path;

      } // end if match

    } // end loop

  } // end function

} // end class

$collection = new related_object_library();

$collection->add(new related_object(1,'Egypt'));
$collection->add(new related_object(2,'USA'));
$collection->add(new related_object(3,'Giza',1));
$collection->add(new related_object(4,'6th october',3));

echo $collection->addressPath(4);
```

Hopefully you're doing your homework now and actually researching the subject, so maybe you're lucky enough to come across this answer.